# Cannot register user subscription on redhat 6

Tags: docker, redhat

Preparing docker image based on redhat 6

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/rhel6

ARG RH_USERNAME=user
ARG RH_PASSWORD=password

...
RUN subscription-manager register \
--username ${RH_USERNAME} \
--password ${RH_PASSWORD} \
--auto-attach \
--release=6.4
...
```

On subscription step build fails with error :

> Proxy error, unable to connect to proxy server. Registering to:
>   subscription.rhsm.redhat.com:443/subscription The command '/bin/sh -c
>   subscription-manager register     --username ${RH_USERNAME}
>   --password ${RH_PASSWORD}     --auto-attach     --release=6.4' returned a non-zero code: 70

It was working before. Any ideas what might be wrong and how to overcome this issue? Thanks )

Comment: If you have RHEL subscription, you should ask RHEL support directly. Moreover, the error message says it all, if you actually read it.

Comment: yes, I see. Could not find where to submit this issue and whether some redhat service is down. That is why posted question here

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have too many subscriptions registered. Every time you run the dockerfile it registers with Red Hat.  Login to Red Hat and delete some of the subscriptions. Mine failed after around 15-20 runs.